# How to insert many elements to std::map with same value

Tags: c++

I want to insert many elements to a map with same value. Like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    map<int,int> m;
    m[2]  = 5;
    m[5]  = 5;
    m[7]  = 5;
    m[9]  = 5;
    m[10] = 5;
    m[15] = 5;
    m[17] = 5;
    m[20] = 5;
    m[21] = 5;
    m[22] = 5;
    //. . .
    m[78] = 4;
    m[80] = 4;
    m[89] = 4;
    m[90] = 4;
    m[95] = 4;
    m[99] = 4;
    //. . .
}
```

**Is there any other way to insert many elements with same value?** A shorter and better way.
Sorry if I asked a silly question.

Comment: You can use a loop and if condition!

Comment: unless your key is approaching millions+,I'm not entirely sure why you're even using a `std::map<>` and not just a `std::vector<>` or `std::array<>`. Regardless, loop it.

Comment: Well, as opposed to this, even `std::map<int, int> m{{2, 5}, {5, 5}, ...};` would work. You could also make a function that takes an initializer list of indices to fill and a value.

Comment: @RahulTripathi The elements are not like 1,2,3,... They are different. So I cannot use loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use a loop:

```
auto const keys = { 2, 5, 7, 9, 10, 15, … };
for (auto&& key : keys) {
    m[key] = 5;
}
```

Comment: In fact, you don't need a named array. `for (auto key : {2,5,7})` will iterate over a temporary one.

Comment: @MikeSeymour `keys` is not an array but an initialiser list. :) I used a variable because I think that long initialiser lists in for loops are ugly.

Comment: Fair enough. Personally, I find unnecessary variables ugly, so thought it worth mentioning that it's also possible to do it in a way more pleasing to my eyes.

Comment: @MikeSeymour When I use `for (auto key : {2,5,7})` the debugger says `Error: expected an expression` Why?

Comment: @Sky: Either you haven't enabled C++11 support, or your compiler is too old to support this particular syntax. (Probably the latter, unless you're also getting errors about `auto` and the new-school `for` loop). You might need to use a temporary variable as shown in the answer, or resort to nastier methods, if that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

A more efficient way would avoid the default construction of the element, like so:

```
m.emplace(2, 5);
m.emplace(3, 5);
// ...
```